# Close form for $x_n$, where $x_{n+1}=\big\lceil \dfrac{x^2_{n}}{x_{n-1}}\big\rceil$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

The sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ is defined by $x_{1}=4$, $x_{2}=19$, and for $n\ge 2$,$$x_{n+1}=\left\lceil \dfrac{x^2_{n}}{x_{n-1}}\right\rceil$$
where $\lceil x\rceil $ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. I am asked to find the closed form for $x_{n}$.

Comment: Almost the same as https://oeis.org/A010907.

Comment: @Clement C "the smallest integer greater" $361/4$ is $91$

Comment: @ProfessorVector My bad, I wrote Floor instead of Ceiling. Here are the terms: `4, 19, 91, 436, 2089, 10009, 47956, 229771, 1100899, 5274724, 
25272721, 121088881, 580171684` and the [log-plot](http://imgur.com/6EA1V5n)

Answer (score 1):

By the definition here https://oeis.org/A008776, you are looking at the Pisot sequence $L(4,19)$. The provided links and references might help you in finding a closed form for this sequence. Note, however, that there might not yet be a closed form known.

Comment: Or http://oeis.org/A004253.

Comment: @ClementC. according to your link, we have $a_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$ with $r_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ , $r_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}$ , $B=\frac{19-4r_1}{r2-r1}$, $A = 4-B$

Comment: The issue is that while this other recurrence formula easily allows to find a closed-form, it would then remain to prove that it's equal to the original sequence. The fact that at least the first 50 terms agree is no such proof. @stity

Comment: @ClementC.I know but I will let OP check whether or not the two sequences are equal

Comment: Note that the OEIS page does not contain information about such a equality. It might thus be possible that such a proof does not yet exist and it might actually be of interest (to someone, somewhere, maybe...^^).